# Correct states in database

Tags: database-design

The following quote is from *Database* by C J Date.

*consistency does not imply correctness. Sadly, therefore, all we can do and all the DBMS can do-is simply assume that transactions are correct, in the sense that they faithfully reflect just those real-world operations they are supposed to.*

Then the books says:

*Note carefully too that this statement is supposed to apply to all possible correct states D1. Clearly, T might in fact not "faithfully reflect the real-world operations it is supposed to" and yet might still produce a correct state D2 from some specific state D1-but that would not be good enough; we want correctness to be a guarantee, not a matter of mere happenstance.*

Can you please if "T might in fact not "faithfully reflect the real-world operations it is supposed to" then how can it produce a correct state?

Comment: [Infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)

Comment: Do you mean the correct state might not be the state that we want?

Comment: No, I don't mean that at all. The theorem demonstrates that it's possible to "produce a correct state D2" from something that does not "faithfully reflect the real-world operations it is supposed to".

Comment: Many thanks.Sorry I still don't understand how that can be a correct state if that does not  "faithfully reflect the real-world operations it is supposed to"?I think of something like this: For example if we want to transfer 100$ from account A to  account B, it may transfer 150$ from A to B. Still the state is correct but it's not what we want. Is this correct?

Comment: Nope. We request to transfer $100. The end result we expect is a debit of $100 on A and a credit of $100 on B. Instead, an infinite monkey decided to perform 10K transfers of $0.01 each.  Or may be transfer $150 from A to B, then $50 from B to A. The end result is as expected, but it did not reflect the real world activity.

Comment: Interesting, many thanks. :) Sorry just this question, please. What do you mean by "perform 10K transfers of $0.01 each"?

Comment: Are you confused by "10K"? It's a shorthand for "ten thousand".

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't know it's ten thousand, many thanks. But sorry I still don't understand " $0.01 each"?

Comment: One hundred dollars equals ten thousand cents; one cent is one hundredth of one dollar, that is $0.01. As a result of tranferring ten thousand cents, $0.01 each time, balances of both accounts change by a sum total of one hundred dollars, giving us the desired result, though the transaction itself does not reflect the actual request.

Comment: Many, many thanks for your excellent explanations. Much appreciated!

Comment: @mustaccio you should post an answer (as it's definitely worthy of an upvote).  Also, kudos for the amount of patience you exhibited on this comment thread.

Comment: @mustaccio' replies are wonderful.

Comment: Why don't you answer our questions in this forum? Since we are junior students? Why we should be professional so you answer our questions? Why you give negative votes to our questions so that we can't ask more questions??? Just mustaccio wonderfully answered my question. Now @ John you mean @mustaccio shouldn't answer my question?